# How to render partialView from another application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have 2 applications published in the same site in iis, so the only diference between both is the virtual path, ex: localhost:2020/app1 and localhost:2020/app2. My problem is that in the app1, I want to call a partialView  from  the app2 and I can't add the references from the app2 to the app1. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Yes the question is the same, but none of the answers resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reasonable way (to me at least) to do this is to move shared partial views to separate library and use RazorGenerator tool to generate code for them. Then when you will reference the library in web projects of both applications those views will be available to use.